# How can i get my form to redirect to a URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want my form to redirect to a url after submitting however i need the form to post to a separate url.

So when the form sends the user goes here to a thank you page:https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation/

The form information gets posted to here: https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json

The form submits but doesnt redirect to: https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation/

Any help would be great!

Here is my code **UPDATED**:

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Test Form - Overture</title>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script> 
 
<script> 
// Form to submit via ajax.
console.log($("form").length) (==0)
$("form").ajaxForm({
"clearForm": false,
"resetForm": true,
"beforeSubmit": function() {
},
"success": function(json) {
if (json.success == true)
{
// Form has submitted successfully.
alert("Thank you for getting in touch.");

} else {
for (name in json.errors) {
$("form").find("[name$='" + json.errors[name] + "']").css("border-color", "red");
};
};
},
"error": function() {}
});
</script> 

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json">

<h2>Test Form</h2>
 <label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="personName" required>
<label>Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="personEmailWork" required>
<label>Phone Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="personPhoneWork" required>
<label>What would you like to discuss with us?</label>
<textarea name="personNote"></textarea>

<input onclick="window.location = 'https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation/';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="MTI4NzQxNTE1NzI=">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated: Your code `$("form").ajaxForm({` runs before the form exists.  Confirm with a line before this: `console.log($("form").length)` (==0)

Comment: Ok so I have put the line in and my script now looks like this:

```<script> 
// Form to submit via ajax.
console.log($("form").length) (==0)
$("form").ajaxForm({
"clearForm": false,
"resetForm": true,
"beforeSubmit": function() {
},
"success": function(json) {
if (json.success == true)
{
// Form has submitted successfully.
alert("Thank you for getting in touch.");

} else {
for (name in json.errors) {
$("form").find("[name$='" + json.errors[name] + "']").css("border-color", "red");
};
};
},
"error": function() {}
});
</script> ```
submits just doesnt do the redirect.

Comment: Update your question with the updated code, dont place it in the comments.

Comment: Ok so I have got a bit further, I replaced:

```<input onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation/';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />```

with:

`<input onclick="window.location = 'https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation/';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />`

However it does not the required fields work just redirects straight away on submit.

Comment: @Grumpy Apologies. I have now updated the code in the question.